# period in sequence of element in vector

Tags: matlab

I have a vector V periodic an I want to write a program which associates to each period the set of different elements in that period and gives its cardinal.

For example:

For the vector `v=(2 3 7 2 7 3 2 3 7 2 7 3)` and cardinal 6, give me only the vector `P=(2 3 7 2 7 3)`.

For The vector `v=(2 3 7 5 8 6 10 11 10 6 8 5 7 3 2 3 7 5 8 6)` and the cardinal 14, give me `P=(2 3 7 5 8 6 10 11 10 6 8 5 7 3)`.

Comment: Attempted to format and make it more readable. Question is still VERY low quality, OP should show some effort on its own, otherwise this will quickly be deleted by the community.

Comment: I've read your problem statement at least 5 times.  I don't understand what it is you want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you have to use build-in function `seqperiod(v)`.
In your case, for example:

```
v=[2 3 7 5 8 6 10 11 10 6 8 5 7 3 2 3 7 5 8 6];
>> seqperiod(v)

ans =

    14
```

Interesting moment: in your second example there aren't full repetition. So we can't really say is it periodic... But `seqperiod` still works and returns `14` as you wish.
go further you can use it in this way:

```
[p, num] = seqperiod(v);
p = 14
num = 1.4286
```

`num` - is a number of repetitions.

Ok. Now you say you need not only the cardinal, but the vector. So you can do it easily:

```
result = v(1:p);
```

Hope it helps!